# convert url using htaccess ...remove and add words

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, seo

This is the url of page.
**http://www.themobilesapp.com/phones.php?title=Apple**

I want a little bit change into this url.
I want this url like this.
**http://www.themobilesapp.com/phones/Apple**

and for this my htaccess code is this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^phones/([A-Za-z0-9]+)?$ phones.php?title=$1
```

but this is not working for me.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Where is the htaccess located?

Comment: Sir, code is not working but url is not converting like this.

Comment: But this code is working for this url.
I can change this url **http://www.themobilesapp.com/phones.php?title=Apple**
into this url
**http://www.themobilesapp.com/Apple**  
using this htaccess code 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)?$ phones.php?title=$1

but i want my url as i discussed. My htaccess is location where all files are located. All are in same folder

Comment: Your rule looks fine. I think multivies are enabled on your server and that is why you cant access the uri. To disable multiviews , add this line to your htaccess **Options -Multiviews**

Comment: This is my htaccess code sir


'Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
Options -Multiviews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

ErrorDocument 404 404error.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^phones/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ phones.php?title=$1

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)?$ tags.php?tag=$1

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ specification.php?url=$1



</IfModule>'

Answer (score 0):

You want to redirect `http://www.themobilesapp.com/phones/Apple` to `http://www.themobilesapp.com/phones.php?title=Apple`.

The following .htaccess rule makes it happen:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^phones/(.*)$ /phones.php?title=$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

I tested this code with [htaccess.mwl.be](http://htaccess.mwl.be/).